# PayPal Express Checkout integration in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I've been searching for PayPal Checkout Express integration for days.

I couldn't find a good document that support this process.

Most of people recommend this website, but the file doesn't exist.
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PayPal-Lib

I already tried PHP version code that PayPal provided, but you know it takes time to convert the codes into Codeigniter MVC platform.

So, can you please tell me where I can get a good tutorial?

Thank you.

Comment: Wrapping a set of functions in a class takes maybe 5 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

I use this, also works for non-Website Payments Pro accounts:
http://www.angelleye.com/download-codeigniter-php-library-for-paypal-payments-pro/